# JAXB - an element with unbounded maxOccurs inside an xsd:all

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

Suppose I have the following java class that maps to the request-body of my REST service to search users.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SearchParams")
@XmlType(propOrder = {})
public class SearchParams {

  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private List<String> role;

  ...
}
```

Note the **propOrder** parameter of the **@XmlType** annotation - it declares that the order in which representing individual attributes appear in an XML file does not matter and thus an **xsd:all** should be used instead of **xsd:sequence** in the generated XSD schema.

However, as you can see, one of the attributes (the **role** attribute) is a list and thus corresponds to an element with an **unbounded maxOccurs**.

It seems that an element with an **unbounded maxOccurs** is not allowed within an **xsd:all complexType**. How do I avoid this problem?

Note that, unlike role, the **firstname** and **lastname** have **maxOccurs** of **1**. I therefore cannot use an **unbounded xsd:choice** instead of **xsd:all** either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you can still modify this model, you could just wrap the role list in its own type, so you would end up with a `<roles>` element with a list of `<role>`s

```
<SearchParams>
    <firstname>firstname</firstname>
    <lastname>lastname</lastname>
    <roles>
        <role>role</role>
    </roles>
</SearchParams>
```

xsd would just be

```
<xsd:schema ... >

    <xsd:element name="SearchParams">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="roles" type="Roles" />
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="Roles">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="role" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

And you'd have two classes. The `Roles` class containing the list. IMO, this is a cleaner approach. (you could just make `Roles` anonymous, but then you'd be stuck with a static inner class)

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

})
@XmlRootElement(name = "SearchParams")
public class SearchParams {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String firstname;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String lastname;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Roles roles;
    ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Roles", propOrder = {
    "role"
})
public class Roles {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> role;
    ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> "If I could change the model class this way than this would look like a great way to solve this issue. Unfortunately I am only allowed to change the annotations"

You could use [`@XmlList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlList.html).

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

})
@XmlRootElement(name = "SearchParams")
public class SearchParams {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String firstname;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String lastname;
    @XmlList
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<String> role;
    ...
}
```

xsd would look like

```
<xsd:element name="SearchParams">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="role">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:list itemType="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

**Note:** As noted [**here**](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_8-Defining-Other-Lists.html#Defining%20Other%20Lists), this method is a "dangerous", the solution in the beginning of my post is preferred over using a `list` of string types. But in your specific case, not sure if I see another way

Comment: If I could change the model class this way than this would look like a great way to solve this issue. Unfortunately I am only allowed to change the annotations.